# Image not recognized by the 'identify' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cygwin, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm trying to upload some photos into my Rails app. But I'm getting:

```
Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError in Admin::ImagesController#create

C:/Users/Dwayne/stream20110816-3680-1hm9dag-0.jpeg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

I know this has been asked before. I thought I'd give my side of the story though, be a bit more verbose than the others, and in doing so help increase awareness of this terrible tragedy.

What platform are you on?

```
# uname
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64
```

Is ImageMagick installed?

```
# identify
Version: ImageMagick 6.4.0 01/19/10 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2008 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

Where is it?

```
# which identify
/usr/bin/identify
```

Tell that to Paperclip:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin"
```

See if all the files and folders work:

```
# identify C:/Users/Dwayne/stream20110817-1264-1xuum8v-0.jpg
stream20110817-1264-1xuum8v-0.jpg JPEG 249x262 249x262+0+0 PseudoClass 256c 8-bit 9.88281kb

# identify /cygdrive/c/Users/Dwayne/stream20110817-1264-1xuum8v-0.jpg
stream20110817-1264-1xuum8v-0.jpg JPEG 249x262 249x262+0+0 PseudoClass 256c 8-bit 9.88281kb
```

Try the same from within the Rails console:

```
# irb(main):005:0> system("identify C:/Users/Dwayne/stream20110817-1264-1xuum8v-0.jpg")
C:/Users/Dwayne/stream20110817-1264-1xuum8v-0.jpg JPEG 360x360 360x360+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 32.3281kb
=> true
```

Still nothing?

Take it to [Paperclip's GitHub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/560).

Still nothing?

Hope that somebody here might know.

Comment: Can you make a copy of the file available?

Comment: Suggestion:  Install a Windows Version of Image Magick (Binary) use an editor like Aptana with a Git Bash.  Make Sure Image Magick is installed in the Windows PATH remove Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin"
as it won't be necessary with it in the path and try again.  If there is no error it has something to do with the Cygwin ImageMagick if not it may be somewhere else.

Comment: Travis, you did it man! Bless you and all your offspring!

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of Travis Pessetto:

Uninstall ImageMagick for Cygwin, install ImageMagick for Windows and try again!